# editing value of inputfield using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

So I have this code:

```
function resetAll(einde) {
if(einde !=1) {
    if(beurt == 0) {
        spelerbolletje.gewonnen += 1;
        document.getElementById("bolletje").value = spelerbolletje.gewonnen;
    } else {
        spelerkruisje.gewonnen += 1;
        document.getElementById("kruisje").value = spelerkruisje.gewonnen;
    }
    }
    setVakjes();
    resetVakjes();
}
```

somehow this sets the value for the value of the winner from 0 to NaN.
does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: how is `spelerbolletje` declared?

Comment: @Tomas at the top of the document as `var spelerbolletje;`

Comment: Check out Shitsu's answer. Incrementing a variable that has not been defined would not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do seems correct. I think the problem is that `XX.gewonnen` has not been initialized.

```
var a = {};
a.gewonnen += 1; // => gewonnen = NaN
```

So, ensure gewonnen is defined:

```
if(XX.gewonnen == undefined) XX.gewonnen = 0;
// rest of your code
```

Comment: all needed variables are declared at the top of the document or when they are needed, so XX.gewonnen has been declared at the top since XX is needed all over the document

Comment: Is it declared like `XX.gewonnen;`, or is it given the value `0` like `XX.gewonnen = 0;`?

Comment: `function fSpeler(naam, beurt, gewonnen) {
 this.naam   = naam;
 this.beurt   = beurt;
 this.gewonnen  = gewonnen;
}`

Comment: nevermind, thanks, it was indeed because XX.gewonnen was not given a value at the beginning, thank :D

Comment: That's cool and all, but is it, at some point, actually given a value?
If it is only declared as `XX.gewonnen;`, then it is simply a place in memory where a value can be stored. 
If it's declared as `XX.gewonnen = 0;`, then JavaScript **knows** that the value is numeric, so it can be incremented.
**EDIT:**
Ah okay, graag gedaan!